# back button and hash in jquerymobile

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, hash

I am building an Android JQueryMobile(1.4.5) + Cordova(3.6.4) mobile app, and playing with it on my Nexus 5 running Lollipop.

I use a JQueryMobile's one-HTML-file per page arrangement: page1.html, page2.html, etc...

The main page is page1.html.

My links are always like `<a href="page2.html">`, `<a href="´page3.html">`.

Sometimes I go from page1->page2->page3, or from page1->page2->page4. When I hit the back button, **page1 dissapears from the DOM** (and it shouldn't cause it's the main page) and page2 is loaded instead. Since only page1 has all the includes it appears as a crash. What I'm doing now is putting all the includes in the HEAD section of page1 and page2...

UPDATE1:

This issue does not seem to happen on a ICS Android device.

Comment: because there is no `hash` you need `href`.

Comment: @omar I thought that navigation history within JQuery mobile was taken care of using hash.

Comment: This is in case you're using _Multi-Page Model_. You're using _Single Page Model_, each page in a separate file.

Comment: @omar But can you explain your comment further please?

Comment: **SPM** = file.html, file2.html, etc. **MPM** (all in one file) = #page1, #page2, etc. External page (SPM) `data-external-page=true` are flagged for removal as jQM doesn't cache external pages by default. if you add `data-dom-cache="true"` to page div, it will be cached.

Comment: @omar thank you for your explanation. I conclude that the problem is not the hashes nor the `data-external-page=true`. But when I hit back button sometime the pages remains white, my main page (file1.html) is removed and in place there is file2.html. This behavior is what I'm trying to understand/fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66939/discussion-between-omar-and-arod).